# How to implement a clocking routine in C

Tags: c, time

I'm trying to create a routine in C that would execute some code every X ms.

I have done it in C# but i need this program in C.

I have tried to implement it using time(0) or clock(), but the problem with these functions is that i can have the system wait a certain amount of time after executing some code.

My intention is to have code executed in chunks of time X.
say X is 25ms
execute some code.
afterwards if i have still time left nothing has to be done until X = 25

If otherwise i have used 30 ms to perform my action i'll have to wait until the next clock tick to do other stuff.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Have a look at the functions `setitimer()` and `pause()`. What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: I did. But they do not help. These functions make the program do nothing for a certain amount of time. I want my code to be run in 25 ms or multiples of it. I do not want to wait 25 ms to perform a new chunk of code.

Comment: The `alarm()` function might help you.

Comment: @Wing Start a timer (with the handler for `SIGALRM` re-arming the timer every time it elapses), then execute your code, then call `pause()`. When the timer elapses (i.e. 25ms from when you started your code), the code continues. This way you can wait until a multiple of 25ms has passed. If you miss a tick, nothing happens as you are not actively waiting for a signal.

Comment: `signal()` or, if you're on POSIX, `sigaction()` + `timer_create(), timer_settime()`

Comment: @alk `alarm()` is too coarse, if OP is on a POSIX-like system, he can use `setitime`, but he doesn't want to tell me.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Ah, yes indeed. I missed the "milli". My bad.

Comment: You say you've done it in C#. It could be nice to show us the code. Those knowing both languages would easily see exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The functions I use in this answer are POSIX functions. On non-POSIX systems like Windows, these functions might not be available.*

The general approach to this kind of problem is to get the system to deliver you a signal every 25 ms or whatever the duration is you have to wait for. One way to do this is to set a timer (e.g. with `setitimer`) and have the signal handler for the corresponding signal (i.e. `SIGALRM` or `SIGVTALRM`) rearm the timer once it elapsed. You can then do your computations and use the `pause` system call to “wait” for the next signal to interrupt you.

If your time periods get much shorter than that, signal delivery might be too slow for your use case. You could call the `clock` function to get the amount of time you used in a loop and wait until it's close enough to a multiple of 25 ms.  This approach has less latency than an approach based on signals, but it keeps your processor busy, so only use it if the duration you have to wait for is really short. This approach has the advantage of being very portable as `clock` is part of standard C.

A third approach is to get the current time and then compute the time you need to wait until the next tick happens and then call `nanosleep` or a similar function to wait for that time. This approach is imprecise (you might sleep for a little more than the time you want to sleep for), but it doesn't cause any drift because you synchronize yourself with the clock every time you find out the current time.

Comment: `man setitimer: [...] POSIX.1-2008 marks getitimer() and setitimer() obsolete,  recommending the  use  of  the POSIX timers API (timer_gettime(2), timer_settime(2), etc.) instead.[...]`
.

Comment: @EOF You could use these as well, but on the other hand, `timer_gettime` was only introduced in Linux 2.6, which is fairly recent. `setitimer` is not vanishing from systems any time soon, but your code may not compile on older systems with `timer_gettime`.

Comment: Linux 2.6 is now more than 11 years old (and AFAICT, EOL). I'd follow the POSIX recommendations, and not use obsolete functions.

Comment: @EOF Linux 2.4 is used on many routers and embedded devices. 11 years is nothing in terms of operating system age. (Windows XP is much older than that!) The demarkation as *obsolete* doesn't mean “don't use this,” it means “there is a new API and the old one is going to be removed from the standard so we don't have duplicate APIs.” As systems are still going to implement the POSIX.1 2001 and 2008 feature sets in the future for compatibility, there is little reason not to use the more stable API, especially considering how slow POSIX 2008 adaption is.

Comment: Both `setitimer()` and `timer_create()` are POSIX.1-2001. `timer_create()` is no less stable an API.

Comment: @EOF `setitimer` is the older call (from 4.2BSD); `timer_create` is much newer and less widespread. But alas, if you only care about modern Linux systems this doesn't matter too much anyway.

Comment: If you want to use things because they are old, why not stick to `gets()`?

Comment: @EOF This is a different case, `gets` is insecure (as opposed to `setitimer` which is perfectly fine security-wise) and the replacement (`fgets`) exists for long enough that it's available everywhere. Of course, if you get a boner from using cutting-edge APIs only, feel free to use them. I prefer to use the more widespread and stable API instead.

Comment: Because, clearly, a function that's been standardized for 14 years is way cutting edge. I do wonder though, are you similarly opposed to using C99?

Comment: @EOF I try to avoid C99 features that cannot be emulated on a C89 compiler. And where do you get the 24 years from? `timer_gettime` has only been standardized for 14 years and it's not even available everywhere (e.g. not on my router). `setitimer` on the other hand is available on all Unices that support sub-second precision timers but a diminishing minority. Tell me, why should I use an API that is more complex and less supported when there is an API that is less complex and more supported that does the very thing I need?

Comment: @EOF Or to make it short, I care more about what's supported than what standards say. If you only cared about what the standard says, why would people use tools like `autoconf` which exist for the precise reason that platforms have poor adoption of standards?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create new thread with an infinite loop which will tick (approximately) every 25 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Below is windows code example similar to multi-threaded games where one of the threads runs at a fixed frequency as accurately as possible. The delays are based on an original reading of a high precision timer, so there's no drift over time. dwLateStep (see example code below) is a debugging aid that gets incremented if a time step is exceeded (the code attempts to catch back up). Sleep(1) can take up to 2 ms on Windows XP, so the code uses Sleep(1) when there is more than 2 ms of delay before the next time step.

However this is different than your description, where it seems you have code that may take longer than a time step. In this case, you run the code in fragments, one fragment for each time step. Say there are 4 fragments, then you could use a switch variable that cycles by 1 on each time step from 0 to 3 then back to 0, with 4 cases.

```
/* code for a thread to run at fixed frequency */
typedef unsigned long long UI64;        /* unsigned 64 bit int */
#define FREQ    400                     /* frequency */
DWORD    dwLateStep;                    /* late step count */
LARGE_INTEGER liPerfFreq;               /* 64 bit frequency */
LARGE_INTEGER liPerfTemp;               /* used for query */
UI64 uFreq = FREQ;                      /* process frequency */
UI64 uOrig;                             /* original tick */
UI64 uWait;                             /* tick rate / freq */
UI64 uRem = 0;                          /* tick rate % freq */
UI64 uPrev;                             /* previous tick based on original tick */
UI64 uDelta;                            /* current tick - previous */
UI64 u2ms;                              /* 2ms of ticks */
UI64 i;

    /* ... */ /* wait for some event to start thread */
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&liPerfFreq);
    u2ms = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart)+499) / ((UI64)500);

    timeBeginPeriod(1);                 /* set period to 1ms */
    Sleep(128);                         /* wait for it to stabilize */

    QueryPerformanceCounter((PLARGE_INTEGER)&liPerfTemp);
    uOrig = uPrev = liPerfTemp.QuadPart;

    for(i = 0; i < (uFreq*30); i++){
        /* update uWait and uRem based on uRem */
        uWait = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) / uFreq;
        uRem  = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) % uFreq;
        /* wait for uWait ticks */
        while(1){
            QueryPerformanceCounter((PLARGE_INTEGER)&liPerfTemp);
            uDelta = (UI64)(liPerfTemp.QuadPart - uPrev);
            if(uDelta >= uWait)
                break;
            if((uWait - uDelta) > u2ms)
                Sleep(1);
        }
        if(uDelta >= (uWait*2))
            dwLateStep += 1;
        uPrev += uWait;
        /* fixed frequency code goes here */
        /*  along with some type of break when done */
    }

    timeEndPeriod(1);                   /* restore period */
```

Comment: Sorry if it took me long enough, but i was unable to respond.
I will try your code asap. thank you in advance for the advice though.